static variable in (embedded) C, instancing of header-file and memory consumption?
I have a header file foo.h with a static int c[100];. If I include foo.h in main.c, it creates another instance of c[100]. If I do so again in bar.c, I get yet another instance:
foo.h:
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

static int c[100];
void foo(void);

#endif

foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

void foo(void)
{
    c[0] = 100;
    printf("c: %d \taddress: %p \t size: %lu\n", c[0], (void *)&c, sizeof(c));
}

bar.h
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

void bar(void);

#endif

bar.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"

void bar(void)
{
    c[0] = 111;
    printf("c: %d \taddress: %p \t size: %lu\n", c[0], (void *)&c, sizeof(c));
}

main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    c[0] = 22;
    printf("c: %d \taddress: %p \t size: %lu\n", c[0], (void *)&c, sizeof(c));

    foo();

    bar();

    return 0;
}

The result shows me I have three blocks in memory at different adresses with 400Bytes each:
c: 22   address: 0x102de4000     size: 400
c: 100  address: 0x102de4190     size: 400
c: 111  address: 0x102de4320     size: 400

So it uses 1200 Bytes of memory, correct?
Besides the fact that this is just an example in which the array could be way bigger (and therefore I would use a pointer with runtime memory allocation):

Is there any optimization happening during compile time?
Is the compiler (I use gcc at the moment) smart enough to realize that only c[0] is used?
Is the operating system (name one) smart enough not to waste the memory?
When I code for embedded microcontrollers, is there any difference to running this program on another OS (memory-wise)?


If you don't want each file that includes foo.h to allocate the space for c, don't define c in the header. It is rarely a good idea to define static variables in a header. The variable is distinct in each translation unit (TU — source file plus included headers), and cannot be directly accessed from outside the TU. You can define static inline functions in a header, but that's normally all that should be unconditionally defined as static in a header.  And be cautious with conditionally defined material (#ifdef DEFINE_C / static int c[100]; / #endif might be OK, but is dubious).

Roughly speaking, you get what you asked for.  If you didn't mean to ask for the three instances of c, revise the code.


So it uses 1200 Bytes of memory, correct?

Yes, 3 * 100 * sizeof(int)


Is there any optimization happening during compile time?


Per default, gcc does some optimizations, yes, but nothing that affects what you've observed afaik.


Is the compiler (I use gcc at the moment) smart enough to realize that only c[0] is used?


It sees three different c[0] since each c is unique for each translation unit. It may be able to figure out that no more than a single element in each array is used if you don't programatically look for proof that you have arrays of 100 ints. The as-if rule lets it optimize away things that don't matter in order to make the program behave as you wrote it to behave.


Is the operating system (name one) smart enough not to waste the memory?


It may overcommit dynamic memory allocations and not actually give you memory until you need it, but in this case, I don't think it has much choice but to give you the 3 static arrays that you requested.


When I code for embedded microcontrollers, is there any difference to running this program on another OS (memory-wise)?


The size of int could be different, so you may see fewer or more bytes allocated. It will always be 3 * 100 * sizeof(int) though.

If you only want one array accessible from all translation units, don't define it in the header file. extern declare it in the header and define it in foo.c. Also, making it static ensures that each translation unit gets a unique instance of the array, which I presume that you don't want.
foo.h:
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

extern int c[100];  // note the extern declaration
void foo(void);

#endif

foo.c:
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int c[100];        // here's the definition

void foo(void)
{
    c[0] = 100;
    printf("c: %d \taddress: %p \t size: %zu\n", c[0], (void *)&c, sizeof(c));
//                                        ^^
//                        use the correct conversion specifier
}

This way, all translation units that include foo.h will use the c that is defined inside foo.c, so there will only be one array shared by them all.

If you only want one array accessible only in foo.c, move the definition from foo.h to foo.c:
foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

// no c defined here
void foo(void);

#endif

foo.c
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static int c[100]; // here's the only definition

void foo(void)
{
    c[0] = 100;
    printf("c: %d \taddress: %p \t size: %zu\n", c[0], (void *)&c, sizeof(c));
}


It sees three different c[0] since each c is unique for each translation unit. - no it sees only one as the compiler sees only one translation unit at the time.

@0___________ It sees three in total when compiling the three TUs and they are all unique since they all have internal linkage.

It can see only one. The compiler is compiling 1 translation unit at a time.

@0___________ ... yes? Is it really that unclear? During the course of compiling the program, the compiler will see 3 definitions of c with internal linkage. It doesn't have to remember that it saw the previous definitions. Each TU may be compiled on a different day, but it'll still be 3 definitions.

It is quite artificial for the human,  but the compiler is compiling only one translation unit. It does not know anything about the previously compiled translation units. It is like creating the instance of the compiler, doing the job and destroying the instance.

But if you specify all three TUs (C source files) on one command line and link the program, then the linker component of the compiler will deal with all three.  And if you do link-time optimization (LTO), they'll be examined.  I doubt that anything changes as a result of LTO, but I've not felt the need to experiment with it.

I also believe that 3,291 angels can dance on the head of a pin — and more if they put their minds to it.

The reason I used 'static' in foo.h is to keep the array's scope within foo.h and foo.c - is this reasonable or what other solutions would be out there to make c[100] 'private' ?

@0___________ The compiler, as in "the different instances of the compiler", compiles one TU at a time and it doesn't even matter if there are three different compilers by different vendors. They see one definition of c each. Three in total. The compilers sees three different c[0], each one unique to the corresponding TU. That's enough philosophy for me on this subject.

@spacetimedivider Making it static ensures one unique c per TU that includes foo.h. Each one will then indeed be "private" and only seen within that TU. You can share pointers to it via function calls, but you can't access another TUs c via its identifier. Do you want one c directly accessible from all TUs (foo.c, bar.c and main.c in this case) or three separate cs, one for each TU?

The general topic I got into here was ‘data encapsulation in c’ and how to borrow patterns from OOP. I read about using static to make a variable ‘private’ and that brought me here.

So, I want one global array c only visible to all functions in TU foo and not be visible to main and bar.

@spacetimedivider Then simply move the definition from foo.h to foo.c

@spacetimedivider I updated the answer to show what foo.h and foo.c should look like to accomplish that in case you haven't gotten it working yet.


Is there any optimization happening during compile time?

There are many, but if you touch the array, the whole array will be there.

Is the compiler (I use gcc at the moment) smart enough to realize that only c[0] is used?

No, the compiler is not a programmer. It is the programmer's job. Also, if you use a reference to this array the compiler does not know why. You may not use the array at all in your code - but it can be used as a DMA buffer, for example.

Is the operating system (name one) smart enough not to waste the memory?

It is not related to OS or bare metal. OS does not deal with static storage duration objects.

When I code for embedded microcontrollers, is there any difference to running this program on another OS (memory-wise)?

No.
You just presented a bad programming pattern that leads to an unnecessary waste of memory.

These are three completely different objects, but by giving them the same name you risk confusing yourself into thinking they might be the same object.
The best thing to do if you are beginner is just to never declare objects static in a header.
Regarding optimization: Because you have passed the address of the whole object to an external function (printf) the compiler that is compiling each of these files cannot possibly optimize away the rest of the array, because it doesn't know what is inside if inside printf.  It must initialize all the other members to zero in case printf accesses them.
On an embedded platform without an MMU, this is probably the end of the question.
On a system with an MMU then if you make the objects much bigger then the linker may allocate addresses to them on separate pages, or spanning multiple pages of memory.  In that case, it might only load the pages into memory when they are accessed, and so the parts that are on pages that are not used will not be loaded.

Not just beginners - everyone should avoid defining variables in header files.

Maybe a static const scalar variable is a justifiable alternative to a macro.  I use defines myself but wouldn't fight to the death over that use-case.

It's not a big deal if the contents of a macro is linked to multiple translation units though. Also macros are most often read-only accessed.
